# GXT 3 XTemplate: Custom Formatter - ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I am trying to use a custom formatter to turn a boolean into "Yes" or "No" and have run into a roadblock.

My IDE (Eclipse) does not indicate any errors but when I try to compile I receive

[ERROR] Annotation error: cannot resolve foobar.client.formatter.YesNoFormatter - exception: ClassNotFoundException

followed by a few other exceptions that appear to stem from this exception. I understand what a ClassNotFoundException indicates however I cannot figure out why I would be getting it since, as my code shows, the YesNoFormatter class is located in foobar.client.formatter and I can access it through

```
GWT.log("True: " + YesNoFactory.getFormat().format(Boolean.TRUE);
```

I am using GXT 3.1.0 and GWT 2.6.1.

Could anybody have an idea of why I am getting this exception? The example given at http://docs.sencha.com/gxt-guides/3/utility/xtemplates/XTemplates.html doesn't mention anything (as far as I can see) about these classes needing to be in specific locations so I am at a loss.

EntryPoint:

```
package foobar.client;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.safehtml.shared.SafeHtml;
import com.sencha.gxt.core.client.XTemplates.FormatterFactories;
import com.sencha.gxt.core.client.XTemplates.FormatterFactory;


public class TestClass implements EntryPoint {

    @FormatterFactories(@FormatterFactory(factory=YesNoFactory.class, name="yesNo"))
    public interface Renderer extends XTemplates {
      @XTemplate(source="yesNo.html")
       SafeHtml render(Boolean b);
    }

    @Override
    public void onModuledLoad() {
      GWT.log("True: " + YesNoFactory.getFormat().format(Boolean.TRUE);
      Renderer r = GWT.create(Renderer.class);

      Window.alert(r.render(true).asString());
    }
}
```

YesNo:

```
package foobar.client.formatter;

import com.sencha.gxt.core.client.XTemplates.Formatter;

public class YesNo implements Formatter<Boolean> {
   @Override
   public String format(Boolean data) {
      if (data == null) {
         return null;
      }
      return (data) ? "Yes" : "No";
   }
}
```

YesNoFactory:

```
package foobar.client.formatter;

public class YesNoFactory {
   public static YesNo getFormat() {
      return new YesNo();
   }
}
```

in foobar

```
<?xml version="1.0 encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module>
   <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
   <inherits name='com.sencha.gxt.GXT'/>

   <entry-point class='foobar.client.TestClass'/>

   <source path='client'/>
</module>
```

foobar/client/yesNo.html:

```
{b:yesNo()}
```

Comment: ähm it sounds like a stupid question, but you didn't post copies from FormatterFactory and FormatterFactories... does that code exist in your project? (sounds really stupid, so please don't kill me)

Comment: FormatterFactories and FormatterFactory are part of GXT 3.1.  I see now that I did not enter the import statements, I will edit my question....

Comment: set the -logLevel to TRACE and check, if there are more errors.

Comment: setting -logLevel to TRACE does not add any additional error.

Comment: There should be more to the error, even if only a full stack trace to go with your [ERROR] line. This really looks like a project classpath setup issue, esp since the error gives the full (correct) class: `foobar.client.formatter.YesNoFormatter`. Do you get the error in Dev Mode or Super Dev Mode? Do you get the error when you compile Java, or when you compile GWT?

Comment: Have you searched for 'validatin newly compiled units'?

Comment: It does appear to be a classpath problem; now I would have to figure out why I see "True: Yes" in the console if the compile cannot resolve  the class.

Comment: I also found that for no arguments {b:yesNo()} does not work but {b:yesNo} does.

Comment: We still need more info to be able to help you. The reason you see logging is that the log statement runs before the template tries to load your class (in dev mode), which is where the failure happens.

Comment: I regret that I am unable to reproduce this on a system where I can easily get a stack trace to post. I have determined that it is a class path issue; I just need to take the time to track it down. The need for this has been overcome by events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My formatter classes (YesNo and YesNoFactory) apparently have to be in a location that gets compiled prior to compiling the client-side code.  After I moved these classes to my 'shared' package - the package that houses code used by the client and server - everything worked.

This was not obvious in the XTemplates portion of the guide at http://docs.sencha.com/gxt-guides/3/utility/xtemplates/XTemplates.html which does not seem to specify where the files used for custom formatters need to be located.  Maybe that should have been obvious but not to me.